# Change value of hyperlink text using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<span id="callnow" class="mhMobile callnow"><a href="tel:01234567890">01234567890</a></span>
```

Is it possible when the page loads, I can change the value of the hypertext label to read `Call Now`?

I tried with this JavaScript but no luck so far:

```
(function(text){
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("callnow a").innerHTML = "Call Now";
    }, 1000);
})(text)
```

**DEMO:**
https://jsfiddle.net/7obax3ta/

Comment: That’s not how getElementById works.

Comment: why not just change how the page is rendered by the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in other answers `document.getElementById()` won't accept css3 selector try`querySelector`.Also remove the unwanted parameters

A sample demo

```js
(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.querySelector(".callnow a").innerHTML = "Call Now";
    }, 1000);
})()
```

```html
<span id="callnow" class="mhMobile callnow"><a href="tel:01234567890">01234567890</a></span>
```

Comment: Apologies here, @SagarV. I had initially tried your result but hadn't executed correctly. I was unclear what to replace in my script. XYZ's response used my full code and I found it easier to test and ultimately implement.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById()` won't accept css3 selectors

Change

```
document.getElementById("callnow a")
```

To

```
document.querySelector("callnow a")
```

Or

```
document.querySelectorAll("callnow a")[0] // 0 specify 0th element.
```

Answer (score 1):

simply :

```
$("#callnow a").text('Call Now');
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather give your a tag an id and call that id in your getElementById, then change the call to innerHTML to .text.

```
<span id="callnow" class="mhMobile callnow"><a id = "callnow-link" href="tel:01234567890">01234567890</a></span>


(function(text){
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("callnow-link").text("Call Now");
    }, 1000);
})(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `getElementById` give id to anchor and call it.

```js
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Call Now";
    }, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="callnow" class="mhMobile callnow"><a id='test' href="tel:01234567890">01234567890</a></span>
```